# Alignment Problem with IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am using blueprint CSS framework for my webpage and now I am facing alignment problem with IE browser..it works okay with mozilla.

Can anyone help me in this please?

Comment: Post your code please :) And what version of IE dose it fail in? (IE 6/7/8 each have their own rendering engines)

Comment: Post a screenshot as well if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to give IE specific styles. You may also want to try out [IE7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).